# This code takes forever to run but doesn't give an error

Tags: python

I am trying to remove all instances of a particular character from a string by replacing the character with an empty string. Here is my code:

```
string1="BANANA"
while string1.count("A") != 1:
    string1 = string1.replace("A","")
```

This code takes forever to run and doesn't give an error. What is the problem?

Comment: Y... But. After the first time that `replace` is done, **ALL** 'A's have disappeared. There will *never* be one left.

Comment: Oh does it replace all at once?

Comment: @aitchessbee The problem is that the Aitchessbee entity failed to look at and/or understand the specification of string.replace while generating the above program

Comment: A simple basic `print (string1)` could have saved you so much trouble.

Comment: [`str.replace` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). Alternatively, this can easily and quickly be seen using a few very simple test cases, e.g. `print("BANANA".replace("A", ""))`.

Answer (score 4):

`string1.replace("A","")` results in `string1` being equal to `BNN`. Thus, `string1.count("A")` equals 0 at that point, not 1, so the loop becomes infinite.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace all "A" but one, you should try this :

```
string1="BANANA"
count = string1.count("A")
s = string1.replace("A","", count-1)
print(s)
```

Output :

```
BNNA
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing as long as there is an "A" in the given string so we should check if count of "A" is greater than 0. Ignoring the fact that `replace` already replaces every occurance of "A" your while loop condition should be something like this.

```py
string1="BANANA"
while string1.count("A") > 0:
    string1 = string1.replace("A","")
```